# Почему функция срабатывает только на первый элемент?

Tags: javascript

Все доброе утро.
Есть 4 ссылки:

```
<a href="#" class="button linkq" style="margin:50px 40px;">{{ $quest->ans_1 }}</a>
<a href="#" class="button linkq" style="margin:40px;">{{ $quest->ans_2 }}</a>
<a href="#" class="button linkq" style="margin:40px;">{{ $quest->ans_3 }}</a>
<a href="#" class="button linkq" style="margin:40px;">{{ $quest->ans_4 }}</a>
```

И выполняю такую функцию:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
        var link = document.querySelector('.linkq');
        link.onclick = function(){
            document.location.href = '/result';
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Но срабатывает только на самую первую ссылку, почему? И как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) возвращает лишь первый элемент, подпадающий под условие. И результат может быть `null`, так что нужно проверять на `null`.
2. Для поиска всех элементов, нужно использовать [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.linkq').forEach(function(el) {   
     el.onclick = function(){   
        document.location.href = '/result';
     };
})
```

```html
<div class="linkq">
123
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('.linkq');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      links[i].onclick = function(){
        document.location.href = '/result';
      }
    }
```